# C# writing to file issue

Tags: c#, text

Im trying to load some stuff from a text file, do some processing and write them to a new text file in C#.

Please have a look at my code below:

Everything seems to be working fine, I can load the stuff, edit them and save them into the text file. however, in the middle of saving them it just stops saving them into the text file for some reason, the while loop runs, I can know this because I'm also logging stuff in the console, and everything's fine in there. but after some point (like 80 lines or something), it just stops adding the new lines to the file.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

```
        StreamReader SR;
        StreamWriter SW;
        string S;
        double temp1;
        double temp2;

        SR = File.OpenText("C:\...Address");
        SW = File.CreateText("C:\...Address");            

        S = SR.ReadLine();

        while (S!=null)
        {

            string[] words = S.Split(' ');

            //editing stuff

            SW.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", temp1, temp2, words[2]);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", temp1, temp2, words[2]);
            S= SR.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Does the program complete, it's just that the output file is not complete? Or does it hang? Or perhaps it crashes with an exception?

Comment: Are `SW` and `SR` pointing to the same file?

Answer (score 4):

Two possible issues:

- It's not clear whether there's one file involved or two. You'll find it tricky to read from the same file you're writing to
- You're not closing the writer, which means it won't get flushed. That may well be the issue - it would certainly explain the symptoms.

The second bullet is best handled with a `using` statement:

```
using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(...))
{
    // Code here
} // writer will automatically be disposed here
```

You should do the same thing for the reader as well. It's less important in terms of data loss, but in general you should dispose anything which implements `IDisposable`, typically to allow resources to be cleaned up deterministically.